# Xamarin: How can I align a logo image in the center of a SkiaSharp Bitmap

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm trying to align a logo in the middle of a `SKBitmap`.

Here is my code:

```
SKBitmap bmpResult = SKBitmap.Decode(imgByteArray);
bitmap.DrawBitmap(bmpResult, 0, 20);
```

I already tried with different images, but the result is the same.

I know that SkiaSharp has `MeasureText`, but, as it says, for text, not for image.

I tried to get my device width with `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width` and divide by 2, but no result.

NOTE that, even if I get a exactly number to divide (for example: `bitmap.DrawBitmap(bmpResult, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / 2, 20);`), when I have different screen densities, the final result will be different, that is, align with one device, unalign with other.

Is anyone knows how can I fix it?

Comment: this is pretty basic math - `(CanvasWidth - ImageWidth)/2`.  If you want to center vertically, use the same calculation for the Y coordinate

Comment: @Jason not worked.

Comment: "not worked" is a useless description of the problem.  Please post the relevant code that you are using, a screenshot of the result, the actual values of your canvas and bitmap.  See [mcve] for more information

Comment: this approach is demonstrated in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/displaying#displaying-in-pixel-dimensions

Comment: @Jason it's already doing, I'm trying to do is align a logo image inside a bitmap, not the bitmap on canvas. With this "basic math" that you commented, in a device the image goes to right near to end, in other, it stays in left-middle. They have different densities. The actual values of my canvas, as I said, I get from `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo`.

Comment: Please, post an answer with an actual test showing that it works so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two bitmaps(bitmap1, bitmap2). Draw the bitmap1 first and then draw the bitmap2. I make two bitmaps in center for your reference.

```
  public partial class Page8 : ContentPage
{      
    SKBitmap bitmap1 = new SKBitmap();
    SKBitmap bitmap2 = new SKBitmap();
    public Page8()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bitmap1 = LoadBitmapResource(typeof(Page8), "App3.image.jpeg");
        bitmap2 = LoadBitmapResource(typeof(Page8), "App3.durian_64.png");       

        // Create the SKCanvasView and set the PaintSurface handler
        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface; ;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        float x1 = (info.Width - bitmap1.Width) / 2;
        float y1 = (info.Height - bitmap1.Height) / 2;

        float x2 = (info.Width - bitmap2.Width) / 2;
        float y2 = (info.Height - bitmap2.Height) / 2;

        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap1, x1, y1);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap2, x2, y2);
    }
    public static SKBitmap LoadBitmapResource(Type type, string resourceID)
    {
        Assembly assembly = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
        {
            return SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

In the screenshot, you would see the bitmap2(green durian) in the center of the bitmap1.

[image]